# UIView resizing but not the SubViews

Tags: objective-c, uiview, subview, cgrectmake

I have an UIView (v1):

```
 ---------------
|   ---------   |
|  |         |  |
|  |         |  |
|  |         |  |
|  | UIImage |  |     
|  |  View   |  |
|   ---------   |
|    UIView     |
 ---------------
```

With an UIImageView (img1) as subview.

When I'm going to resize the UIView:

```
int img1int = v1.frame.size.height+(img1.frame.size.height - img2.frame.size.height);
v1.frame = CGRectMake(v1.frame.origin.x, v1.frame.origin.y, v1.frame.size.width, img1int+20);
```

The image resize with the view, but **I want to just resize the view, and let the image with the normal height**.

The **int** is a calculus that I made, for the UIView has its height related to the height of UIImageView (img1).

Any idea how to resize **only the UIView**?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use UIScrollView instead of UIView and setContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height) and it will resize correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off `"Autoresize Subviews"` on your `UIView v1` attributes in the XIB file.

By default this is checked.

This works for your app above. Alternatively, if you wanted some children to auto-resize and some not, then on each child you can disable the auto-size height/width (the red arrows within the "Auto-sizing" box.

Your UIImageView will then stop resizing.