# How to rotate a UIImageView without resizing it?

Tags: objective-c, image, rotation, transform

My current problem is that when i try rotating a UIImageView it rotates but it resizes too.
Here's the code i'm using:

```
 CGAffineTransform a = _player.image.transform;
 _player.image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(a, angle);
```

_player is a Player object and image is a Player UIImageView variable.

Thanks for the tip.

EDIT:

pic 1: Application launched

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnq66.png)

i can move a player by touching it and using the pad

pic 2: i want to move the car and rotate it as the pad but the car resizes and doesn't move.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiYX.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: How does it resize? Screenshot before and after?

Comment: possible duplicate of [objective -c resizing image issue during rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699077/objective-c-resizing-image-issue-during-rotation)

Comment: Rather than reposting, please edit your earlier question to add information, clarify, or otherwise make it more answerable. Editing it bumps it to the top of the "active questions" list, and the front page, where it will get new attention from other users. For more, please see [How do I get attention for unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)

Comment: thanks for the tip, i didn't know the bump thing as i'm new. i'm osting the screenshots now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set autoResizingMask of the view property to UIViewAutoresizingMaskNone

Comment: Did you apply this transformation on rotation of device? If yes, can you try just somewhere without rotating the device? like in some button action or something..

Answer (score 0):

Try turn off "Autoresize Subviews" attribute (in the XIB file) for superview of the UIImageView. You can found this answer here too: [UIView resizing but not the SubViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762110/uiview-resizing-but-not-the-subviews) .